# How to display 'sum' inside text box in cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    Func<int,int,int> Sum = (a, b) => a + b;
}

//inside table
<td>@Sum(3,4)</td>
```

This outputs the correct answer, Although I would like it outputted inside a text box which can be adjusted (so the data can be posted back)...my attempt....

```
<td><input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">                      
 @Minus(@products.ReorderLevel, @products.StockLevel) 
 </input>
 </td>
```

It is saying input element is empty and cant have a closing tag.

Ideally I would like 2 small buttons after the text box '+' % '-' which will increment or decrement the value in the text box when clicked....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'value' attribute to set the value of a text input field

```
<td><input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" 
           value="@Minus(products.ReorderLevel, products.StockLevel)" /> 
</td>
```

For changing the values you're gonna have to write some JavaScript. Look into [jquery](http://jquery.com/) for a simple way to look up and manipulate DOM-objects such as your textbox (the `$("..")`-stuff in the example below

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/path/to/your/jquery.version.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
     // Declare a function to increment a value
     var incrementField = function()
     {
         var newValue = 1 + parseInt($("#name").val());
         $("#name").val(newValue);
     };
     // Declare a function to decrement the value
     var decrementField = function()
     {
         var newValue = parseInt($("#name").val()) - 1;
         $("#name").val(newValue);
     };
</script>
```

and call it from your html:

```
<button onclick="incrementField()">+</button>
<button onclick="decrementField()">-</button>
```

This is very basic, untested and prototype quality stuff. A different approach is to use [jQuery .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to hook up your increase/decrease logic.

**Update: Working jsFiddle example here:** http://jsfiddle.net/Am8Lp/2/

Set an ID to your buttons and use the following javascript:

```
 // This creates a callback which called when the page is fully loaded
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Set the initial value of the textbox
    $("#name").val('0');

    // Create a click handler for your increment button
    $("#increaseButton").click(function(){
         var newValue = 1 + parseInt($("#name").val());
         $("#name").val(newValue);
    });
    // .. and your decrement button
    $("#decreaseButton").click(function(){
        var newValue = parseInt($("#name").val()) - 1;
        $("#name").val(newValue);
    });
});
```

Finally add an ID to your buttons and remove the old click handler

```
<button id="increaseButton">+</button>
<button id="decreaseButton">-</button>
```

Comment: Once inside the function, you likely won't need the "@" symbols prefixing e.g. "@Minus(products.ReorderLevel, products.StockLevel)"

Comment: thats great thanks...and do I use some form of JS to increment or decrement the total in the box when the plus or minus button is pressed

Comment: Fixed the errors @davidsleeps pointed out, and added one way to handle the increment and decrement stuff

Comment: Added jquery .click example and set up a working example in jsFiddle

Comment: This jsfiddle should put you on the right track. I'm using the same class on every button and hooking the click event to that. Then I extract the id from the button and use it to find the right text Box
http://jsfiddle.net/G2bu5/5/

Comment: If you looked at the latest fiddle I posted, I updated it now with a new url http://jsfiddle.net/G2bu5/5/